# Canvas onclick object, animate once

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to click on an 'object' and have it animate to an 'inventory'. Which I suppose would be an array or a series of objects.

How can I make clicks on an image trigger an animation to the position and
change its values?

```
//window to canvas code omitted 
//also find mouse co-ordinates code omitted
//init such as 'context' omitted.
onclick = function(e) {
  clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawImage(cupcake, 0, 0 , 50, 50,);
}
```

Comment: You have to have it's dimensions/position stored and check to see if the mouse click is within those dimensions. If that condition is true, then fire your animation. [My old project](http://cssdeck.com/labs/canvasgui) may help you, it does this exactly

Comment: I'll take a close look, thank you very much. harry. here is what I have so far http://harrywatson.altervista.org/momo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want in browser animation, I would recommend CSS animation/transitions. They are relatively smooth and well supported across browsers.

Here is a demonstration of CSS animation, which can be controlled be javascript. 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation3

Comment: This cannot affect elements in a canvas

Comment: Yes css animations are fabulous but not useful within the 'canvas' element which needs a script. Thanks for the reminder. Html elements can be placed with css in front of the canvas which could make some nice 'lossless' game effects on loading.

Comment: @Harry Yeh but if you place elements in from of the canvas, then their isn't much purpose for the canvas. If you do want the CSS animations, you probably shouldn't use canvas at all.

Comment: css animations would be good on the page and then use js for animations within the canvas/game. I know someone's made a whole movie using  css

Comment: If you're asking how to move elements around a web page that's a completely different question than this one which involves moving them around on a canvas

Comment: Yes it's the canvas I want to get a handle on. I can animate something and I can get it to recognise a mouse click but not animate on click. That can be done with html objects like buttons or images but I'm looking to click a canvas element in order to animate it.